# 'Charts' gives errors when i import it in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, charts

I'm trying to create a line chart in swift 3 and i'm trying to try out 'Charts', but when I import it it gives me all these errors, and i can't find anyone else who had similar problems.

Here are the errors:

https://gyazo.com/0fba3848dc74344c5b6d60b5da4b0546

What causes these errors and what can I do about it?

Comment: The error messages mention NSAttributedStringKey. That's iOS 11 only. Are you trying to compile this for iOS 10 or earlier? Are you using Xcode 8? You can't do either of those things. You need to be using Xcode 9, Swift 3.2 or Swift 4, iOS 11.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) @psydsr96.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the Swift Version 4 of Charts.  You have to download the Swift 3 version.  On Github, click on the Releases tab and you will find it there as seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: How do I install it? I have used cocoapods for my other pods.

Comment: In your podfile remove the Charts line and install.  This will remove the new version.  Then add the line:

    pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.3'

Install again.  Should work perfectly after that.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper version running.  Go to terminal.  type: open -a XCode podfile.lock  This will show you the version of Charts that you are running.  What version is it?

Comment: Under pods it says 3.0.4 and under dependencies it says 3.0.3

Comment: So you didn't remove 3.04 successfully.  Open your pod file and remove the Charts line. Save it and type: pod install.  This will remove Charts (I know the install command is counter-intuitive.)   type: open -a XCode podfile.lock to confirm it's gone.  Open your pod file again and add the line: pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.3' to your pod file.  Save it.  Finally, type: pod install to install the correct version.

Comment: It still installs 3.0.4 for some reason

Comment: The last thing I can think of is that your are having an issue with CocoaPods cache.  Try cleaning it.  Good luck:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_cache_clean

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Remove the current version from Xcode and re-download it [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I followed the instructions for manual installation, and it works fine.